# Match function doesn't work with variable but it works with underlying value

Tags: excel, vba, match

I came across a peculiar problem where following piece of code

```
Dim bankStatementWb As Workbook
Dim tasksListWb As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim feedRow As Long
Dim amountValue As Double

amountValue = CDbl(bankStatementWb.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value)

feedRow = Application.Match(amountValue,tasksListWb.Worksheets(1).Range("I:I"), 0)
asd
```

works fine, finding me the row numbers I need, with some exceptions.

Interestingly, if I replace the "amountValue" with its value, in this case 80204.4, then Match will work.

Nothing seems to help, even forcing the value to be double (CDbl)...

Comment: And if you ask to show you the difference of both values, how much do you get?

Comment: Floating point matches are inherently finicky. You'd probably be best off rounding all your values to some set number of decimal places before you compare them. This has to do with the way computers store decimal values; the displayed value 80204.4 might actually be stored as 80204.399999999999999 in memory, so it returns false when checking whether that equals 80204.4.

Comment: I was checking that with subtracting the both values and I was getting 0, so I think this might not be the case... However, I'll try with rounding the value to the second decimal.